# how to get the time after two minutes

Tags: python, shell, unix, time, tcl

I have a to execute a command automatically after two minutes from the current date using shell scripting. Lets say my current time is in below format. The script should read the current time ,add two minutes to the existing time which will be 2014-09-10T09-23-34 and then execute the remaining script.

```
date +"%Y"-"%m"-"%d"T"%H"-"%M"-"%S"
```

2014-09-10T09-21-34

Comment: Use `sleep 120` ??

Comment: actually i am supposed to read the current time and then add two minutes to the current time. The script reads the future time and then execute when the future time comes

Comment: read my answer if you insist on not using sleep

Comment: if you have a datetime object just add two minutes to it

Comment: you can use 'sched' module to schedule an eventi in the future: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html

Comment: WTF has this got to do with Tcl (other than that Tcl's yet another language which you can do this in)? Seriously, _get your sh*t together_ and work out more precisely what you want to know before asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date-string in bash:

```
echo "Current: " $(date +"%Y"-"%m"-"%d"T"%H"-"%M"-"%S")
echo "+2 min : " $(date --date="@$(($(date +%s)+120))" +"%Y"-"%m"-"%d"T"%H"-"%M"-"%S")
```

prints

```
Current:  2014-09-10T15-58-15
+2 min :  2014-09-10T16-00-15
```

Read the time from string and print +2min string

```
str="2014-09-10T15-58-15"
new=$(date --date="@$(($(
        IFS="-T" read y m d H M S <<< "$str";date --date="$y-$m-${d}T$H:$M:$S" +%s
    )+120))" +"%Y"-"%m"-"%d"T"%H"-"%M"-"%S")
echo "From string: $str"
echo "String +2m : $new"
```

prints

```
From string: 2014-09-10T15-58-15
String +2m : 2014-09-10T16-00-15
```

Execute an command from the "current time", as others already says, use:

```
sleep 120 ; commands...
```

Execute a command 2 minute later as is specified in the string:

```
sec2date() { date --date="@$1"; }
countdown() { s="$1";while (($s)) ; do printf "%04d\r" $s; sleep 1; let s--; done; }

str="2014-09-10T16-55-10"

current=$(date +%s)
stringsec=$(IFS="-T" read y m d H M S <<< "$str";date --date="$y-$m-${d}T$H:$M:$S" +%s)
wanted=$(date --date="@$(($stringsec + 120))" +%s)

diffsec=$(($wanted - $current))
(( $diffsec > 0 )) || { echo "Can't execute in the past" ; exit 1; }

echo "time in the string :" $(sec2date $stringsec)
echo "+2min = execute at :" $(sec2date $wanted)
echo "current time       :" $(date)
echo "need wait          :" $diffsec
countdown $diffsec
echo "running at         :" $(date)
```

prints

```
time in the string : st sep 10 16:55:10 CEST 2014
+2min = execute at : st sep 10 16:57:10 CEST 2014
current time       : st sep 10 16:56:52 CEST 2014
need wait          : 18
running at         : st sep 10 16:57:10 CEST 2014
```

or, simply use the `at` command. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sleep(120)
```

the program will get to the line this command is in, wait 120 seconds (2 minutes), and continue its execution.

Next time please try googling first, you can find it easily through there.

**EDIT:** if for some reason you insist on not using `sleep` you can use:

```
import time
start = time.time()
while (time.time() - start) < 120:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

use (cmd is your command):

sleep 120 && cmd

eventually use this python 2.7 script (saved as cron.py):

```
import datetime
import os
import sys

d = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)
txt = "%s %s %s %s * %s " % (d.minute, d.hour, d.day, d.month, sys.argv[1])
print txt
os.system( "echo '" + txt + "' >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root")
```

and then run:

python cron.py cmd

In that case it won't be exactly 120s.